# how to make a flash drive read-only on other computers

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus, read-only

How do I make a USB flash drive or a flash drive partition so that it would  be read-only and less vulnerable to malware?
Maybe making the flash drive be treated as a CD on other computer so that its not possible to write any kind of data into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires special hardware or firmware support, and is not something you can reliably do with stock flash drives, short of virtually mounting a ISO9660 image file.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to use [Sordum's NTFS Drive Protection tool](http://www.sordum.org/8117/ntfs-drive-protection-v1-3/). It can protect against some (but not all) viruses on flash drives, mainly those that exploit Autorun. The drive does need to be formatted as NTFS for this to work.

Comment: Can you explain what does and include a link to the utility? I took a look at the software in question and it doesn't seem to be spam but an explanation of the function of this software would be really useful. http://www.sordum.org/8117/ntfs-drive-protection-v1-3/